# When dealing with possession will a stronger personality win

Tags: dnd-5e, homebrew

Since there's no demonic possession in D&D 5e's published material, how is PC possession handled in general when homebrewing: will a stronger personality, ex charisma, win out or is there more to it?

Comment: You say you aren't counting homebrew but there are no demons who possess living creatures in the rules. What exactly is your question?

Comment: @DavidCoffron Sorry it seems I was misinformed I'll edit my question to reflect that. Note to self: never read DnD wiki.

Comment: @MageintheBarrel That note to self **never trust what you read on DnDWiki** is best put in bold. :)

Answer (score 4):

There's no demonic possession, but there is [ghostly possession](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Ghost#content).

Ghostly possession works as follows:

> **Possession (Recharge 6)**: One humanoid that the ghost can see within 5 ft. of it must succeed on a DC 13 Charisma saving throw or be possessed by the ghost...
>   The possession lasts until the body drops to 0 Hit Points, the ghost ends it as a Bonus Action, or the ghost is turned or forced out by an effect like the Dispel Evil and Good spell. When the possession ends, the ghost reappears in an unoccupied space within 5 ft. of the body. The target is immune to this ghost's Possession for 24 hours after succeeding on the saving throw or after the possession ends.

Charisma will prevent the initial attack but it won't let you "escape" possession.

There are no established rules for home brewing, so there's not much we can tell you about that.  Simply adding that ability to a demon is one way to do that, but only you (the DM) can decide if it feels right, or fits the story/world the way you want it to.

Comment: I tossed in a coda on your home brew point, please review to see if you feel it adds value, and if not by all means revert.